# Give the EL eqns of $\int_0^1 (\dot x_1^2 + \dot x_2^2 - k^2(x_1 + x_2)^2) dt$ and solve the coupled system of 2nd order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

Find the EL eqns of
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 (\dot x_1^2 + \dot x_2^2 - k^2(x_1 + x_2)^2)\: dt$
where $x_1 = x_1(t), x_2=x_2(t)$, $k$ constant
and solve the system of equations

E-L eqns from: $\displaystyle 0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x_i}}\right)$
and $f(t,x_1,x_2, \dot x_1, \dot x_2) = \dot x_1^2 + \dot x_2^2 - k^2(x_1 + x_2)^2$

I have
\begin{align*}
    0 
    &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot x_1 }\right)\\
    &= -2k^2(x_1 + x_2) - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}2\dot x_1\\
    \Longrightarrow  0 &= \ddot x_1 + k^2(x_1 + x_2)\\
   \text{and } 0 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot x_2}\right)\\
    &= -2k^2(x_1 + x_2) - \frac{d}{dt}2\dot x_2\\
    \Longrightarrow 0 &= \ddot x_2 + k^2(x_1 + x_2)
\end{align*}
Is

> \begin{align*}
> 0 &= \ddot x_1 + k^2(x_1 + x_2)\\
> 0 &= \ddot x_2 + k^2(x_1 + x_2)
> \end{align*}

the system of equations?

And how do I find the general solution to this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of equations you have looks correct to me. To solve the system, note that by setting:
$$u=x_1+x_2,\quad v=x_1-x_2$$
We obtain the system (to obtain the first equation, add the two equations in your system, then subtract them for the second equation):
$$\ddot{u}+2k^2 u=0$$
$$\ddot{v}=0$$
This is an uncoupled set of ODE's. After solving this, we can recover $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ using that:
$$x_1=\frac{u+v}{2},\quad x_2=\frac{u-v}{2}$$

Comment: very neat solution. The question asks for the general solution, however the integral is real so do you think I should take the real part of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: If you express the general solution for the $u$ equation as a linear combinations of sines and cosines instead of complex exponentials, you don't have to worry about taking real parts, just take the arbitrary constants in the solution to be real.